How to install the required package for wasysym.sty in Fedora 40
I am in a Fedora 40 system getting LaTeX Error: File 'wasysym.sty' not found.. What is the package to be installed? And how do I install it?
I tried sudo yum uninstall texlive-wasysym.noarch which installed texlive-wasysym version 11:svn54080-71.fc40 but then I got a load bunch of other errors, so I assume it is not the right one.
I am getting the error because I used \apprle.

uninstall installed the package?   I think you should just need to install texlive-wasysym https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/texlive/texlive-wasysym/ but I don't have a fedore texlive to test.

Fedora 40 prefers dnf (over yum) for installations. The command you are looking for is "dnf install texlive-wasysym" (as root or through sudo), not "uninstall"!

The solution was 2 steps:
sudo dnf install texlive-wasysym

sudo dnf install texlive-collection-fontsrecommended-11:svn54074-71.fc40.noarch

